# Vault query when using Token-SDK in Corda

Tags: corda

I want to know the queries (while running the Template Cordapp for Token-SDK through command line) that can be used to see the token or states present in the vault of a node when using Token-SDK in Corda.

Answer (score 0):

You're very limited with the command line, you need to write your own flows or services that query the vault and return results; then on top of that you would write a client or a webserver to call those flows/services.

For instance if you write a webserver; you can call the API's with Postman and see the results in JSON format.

- [Client sample](https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/cordapp-example/clients).
- [Webserver sample](https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/spring-webserver).

Answer (score 0):

All tokens are issued either as FungibleToken or NonFungibleToken. You could query the vault for FungibleToken or NonFungibleToken. Though you would need some custom logic to differentiate between multiple token types.

Comment: How do we vault query a fungible token using RPCOps ? Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Use - rpcOps.vaultQuery(com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.contracts.states.FungibleToken.class)

Comment: You could also query a particular TokenType using a queryCriteria